# Trigger a function when message received in Azure IoT Hub

Tags: python, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

First I would say I'm new to Azure.
Most of my cloud experience comes from AWS.

I'm using IoT Hub with a connected device that sends a message every 1 min.

So far what I did what according to this guide from the Microsoft team:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps

Now, I wanted to create something like Lambda function in AWS, and from what I understand in Azure they called it Azure Functions. I wanted to create a function that gets triggered every time a new message from my device has been received, do something (let's say add 1) and then send it back (so I can pull the 'new' data to my backend).

So far what I did was to create a new "Azure Function" (which I guess it's like a container to functions?)
And then I try to create a new function by click 'Add new' and click on the 'IoT Hub (Event Hub)' template. But when I get to my code and try to test it I get a 404 response. Do I need to create something else? Do I need to create a new 'event' in my IoT Hub? Do I need to create a new 'Event Hub'?

Thanks!

P.s
I try to google it but must of the answers were with the old portal or in C#, I'm using Node and Python.

Comment: Hello @itaik , did the responses below answered your question? Please mark it as answer to help others finding the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This scenario is covered in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/functions-js-iot-hub-processing/processing-data-from-iot-hub-with-azure-functions/) sample. The sample is in JavaScript. It writes the messages to a database, but you can change this part if you want.

To answer some of your other questions:
IoTHub comes with a built-in Event Hub, so no need to create anything else! Your Azure Function will use an Event Hub trigger to subscribe to events coming from IoT Hub. By default, every event that a device sends to IoT Hub will end up on that endpoint, so to 'create' a new event, use the device SDK (on a device or on your machine) to send a message to IoT Hub.

You mentioned 'sending it back', but in most cases you don't have to respond to IoT Hub messages. You can for instance store the message in a database and build a web application that reads from that database. You could also get real-time updates in your web application, but that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to answer your queries below:-

> I wanted to create a function that gets triggered every time a new
> message from my device has been received, do something (let's say add 1)
> and then send it back (so I can pull the 'new' data to my backend).

If you mean sending the data back to `IoTHub`, that doesn't seem logical to me as the manipulated data is something not sent by device. I would rather treat my Azure function as the backend and save/send the data in some persistent store or a message broker where it can be accessed by other consumer(s).

> So far what I did was to create a new "Azure Function" (which I guess
> it's like a container to functions?) And then I try to create a new
> function by click 'Add new' and click on the 'IoT Hub (Event Hub)'
> template. But when I get to my code and try to test it I get a 404
> response. Do I need to create something else?

There are couple of ways by which you can create the Azure function with Built-in endpoints that is compatible with Event Hub as the trigger. Check below image. Relevant information about Built-in endpoints can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin).

[image: Built-in endpoint]

> Do I need to create a new 'event' in my IoT Hub?

Not sure exactly what you mean by this. The way the flow work is

1. Send telemetry messages from device. NodeJS example can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device_with_sas.js).
2. You need to add message routing for messages arriving at the IoTHub should be received in Built-in endpoints. Check image below for telemetry message routing to Built-in endpoint.

[image]
Similarly you can route device twin change events, lifecycle events to Built-in endpoint.

> Do I need to create a new 'Event Hub'?

Not required, as the Built-in endpoint is Event Hub compatible. Check documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin). Unless, you have a specific need as per your business use case a custom Event hub endpoint is not required.

> But when I get to my code and try to test it I get a 404 response.
> Now, we need to trigger the azure function whenever a new event/message is received on the Built-in Endpoint. You can do this by couple of ways.

1. [Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function)
2. [Command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli?tabs=bash%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-javascript)
3. [VS code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code?pivots=programming-language-javascript)

The main point to be noted above is your azure function binding[trigger] is set correctly in the function.json file. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=javascript#version-2x-and-higher-1) is how the trigger looks like.
`MyEventHub` and `myEventHubReadConnectionAppSetting` value should be picked from Application settings. Check image below.
[image]

I suggest you to go through this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=javascript#version-2x-and-higher-1) for in depth understanding of how the Event hub trigger works with Azure function.

Once you have all the above steps done, you can open your Azure function app in portal and go to Functions section in the Function app blade. There you can monitor, code & test, check integration for your Azure function.

Comment: I can't find myeventhub and connectionappsetting in "Application settings". Is it in the function app configurations?

Comment: You need to add those yourself myEventHub value is the eventHub name and the myEventHubReadConnectionAppSetting  is the connectionstring of event hub